# wxPython - application updater

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Iv built an appplication with wxPython and cefPython. Now I am building a updater to update my software.

The process is as follows:

1. Updater is called once the app starts
2. Updater checks with the API
3. If version is older than API, it downloads the new zipped package
4. After the download is done, it closes the application
5. Closed, now it should extract the new files,
6. Extracted, now it must open the program again.

I think the problem comes in at **Point number 4** because I think the process is closed so now the rest of the steps does not happen.

How should I do this so that the updater (that Im importing and calling from the main program) does not also close, if that is the issue.

Here is some code:

```
import updater (updater.py)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    timer = None
    timerID = 1
    def OnInit(self):       
        if not USE_EVT_IDLE:
            print("Using TIMER to execute the CEF message loop work")
            self.CreateTimer()
        global frame
        frame = MainFrame()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        frame.Show(False)       
        **thread.start_new_thread(checkForUpdate, ()) --- This is where im calling the update function**
        return True



def checkForUpdate():
    print("Checking for update: %s" % time.ctime())
    updater.callAPI()
    threading.Timer(120, checkForUpdate).start()
```

Thanks

Comment: One solution would be to have an external helper application that will launch the main application again. This could be a simple C/C++ program, so that any dependencies are minimal and so that it does not require any updates in the future.

Comment: Hey, I ended up makeing the updater a seperate EXE file, and then just starting that process in the udpate function with some parameters. Now it works well.. NOw I just need to remove the icon from the task bar when killing the app

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using wxPython, why not use its builtin updater module? I think they were added in the latest version of 2.8 and it's definitely included in 2.9. They basically took the Esky project and wrapped it in a wxPython helper to make it even easier to use. I wrote a tutorial on the subject here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/07/12/wxpython-updating-your-application-with-esky/

And you can read about esky here:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky

I have also heard of the "goodasnew" project, but I haven't tried it as of yet:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/goodasnew/